# Adapting my website to different reslutions

Tags: css, resolution, screen-resolution

I have been working on this website and it is almost over.. until I discovered my computer is on **a high resolution (1920 x 1080px)**.
I tested my website in 1024x768px and it was... not what I expected.

Anyway I searched far and wide around the web and there are still questions that I did not find answers to, so I am here to ask you , hoping to find an answer !

First of all, what I want about my website, is to be comfortable to any screen resolution on computer, from 1024 to 1920.
Also, I want it to be comfortable when you reduce the window (you know, like when you make a webpage only cover half the screen).

*( English is not my mother tongue so I hope it will still be understandable for you guys.. )*

1- I began using **px**. That does not work on lower resolutions, users have to unzoom. So now I am using **%** as advised on the web. But now when I reduce my window on the left of my screen, it adapts too, but too much.. I want it to make a horizontal scrollbar appear when you reduce the window too much.
SO basically that is my question, **what should I do ?** I find many websites that work fine (like this one, if you reduce the window a horizontal scrollbar appear !)
Maybe combining px and % ? I don't know, I really have no idea what to do.

2- Is the **resolution of the screen** comparable **to the size of the window** on a screen ? For example, my resolution is : 1920x1080px
If I put my window on the half left of my screen, will be equivalent to a resolution of 1920x5040 px ?

3- For **phones and tablets**, is it just a question of smaller resolutions ? Or is there something more ?

Thank you so much for helping me on this one !
Cheers,
Bill

Comment: "what should I do ?" This is quite broad. It would be better for you to show *a minimal example* of your working code and where you encountered a problem.

Comment: This question as-written is far too broad for SO. But to answer it anyway: learn responsive design, use media queries.

Comment: thanks for your answers guys ! 
basically ; if I pick `px`, my content is not comfortable for users using another resolution. If I pick `%`, my content will shrink when I reduce the window, but in that case I want my content to stay the same size and just a horizontal scroll bar to appear. (just check with this website; reduce the window on the left half of your screen, the content is not reduced, but a scroll bar appears).

So more specifically my question was ; how to deal with both of this problem ?

Comment: I think I got a beginning of an answer with `min-width` but I wanted to see if other solutions existed... like **media queries** ? I'll check that. is that better solution than `min-width` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all, you need to have a container of all your element. Every percentage value is based on it's container. And for scrollbar, may there in your site container have CSS `overflow: hidden`, so you need to remove it or change it to `overflow: auto`
2. I think you meant the content will be shrink horizontally and expand vertically. This is because you don't have any container to wrap each element with percentage width. So you need to have it and set `min-width` of that container.
3. For touch device, your site will zoomed out based on how big is your container.

Comment: waw already a lot of answers, thank you so much guys.

For the scroll bar it was not a question of 'overflow:hidden', it is just that the content just shrinks and shrinks when I reduce the window (which is normal because I set percentage).
Anyway with 'min-width' it works fine (well I still have some work to do to change all my widths in my CSS !.. guh)

On what resolution would you base your 'min-width' though? Like, all the min-width I'll set must be coherent to one resolution, the '1024x720px' for example ? ( just checking if I understood well before starting to change everything :) )

Comment: `min-width` is backup for your percentage value. So your element not always base on screen size. When you have screen with 1024px width, if you have `min-width: 1280px` for example, your will see a scrollbar appear.

Comment: omg that's it ! I put everything on percentage and I just set a `min-width`for my `container` div, no need set `min-width` to all elements !
I haven't even thought about it.. duh

thanks a lot !

Comment: media queries are about adapting the CSS stylesheet to the resolution detected. So it is a better, wider solution, but in my case it is not really needed, right ?

Comment: Then, feel free to mark as answer. Glad I can help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a simple question to answer.  What you want to do is stop thinking in terms of pixels.  Read about responsive design.  Read about the elastic nature of HTML, and its ability to reflow your document.  Read about media queries.

Basically, from a starting point, *DON'T* specify explicit widths for anything unless it is necessary.  s and

s automatically stretch to your full screen width, regardless of resolution.

You have quite a bit of a learning curve ahead of you, I'm afraid.  Good luck and read lots.